# How to scrape HTML using Python for NOWTV available movies

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm creating a research dataset, over time, that will give me the available movie names on NOWTV.

This would be from URL (https://www.nowtv.com/stream/all-movies)

Output to be each movie that is available.

Unsure where to start, would like to use Python and Beautiful Soup. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                          
import urllib2                                                         

url = "https://www.nowtv.com/stream/all-movies"                    

data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mimic what the page is doing in terms of paginated results (https://www.nowtv.com/stream/all-movies/page/1) and extract movies from the script tag of each page. Although the below could use some re-factoring it shows how to obtain the total number of films, calculate the films per page, and issue requests to get all films using Session for efficiency. Result is 1425 movies.

```
import requests
import re
import json
import math
import pandas as pd

titles = []
links = []
base = 'https://www.nowtv.com'
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    res = s.get('https://www.nowtv.com/stream/all-movies/page/1') 
    r = re.compile(r"var propStore = (.*);")
    data = json.loads(r.findall(res.text)[0])
    first_section = data[next(iter(data))]
    movies_section = first_section['props']['data']['list']
    movies_per_page = len(movies_section)
    total_movies = int(first_section['props']['data']['count'])
    pages = math.ceil(total_movies / movies_per_page)

    for movie in movies_section:
        titles.append(movie['title'])
        links.append(base + movie['slug'])

    if pages > 1:
        for page in range(2, pages + 1):
            res = s.get('https://www.nowtv.com/stream/all-movies/page/{}'.format(page)) 
            r = re.compile(r"var propStore = (.*);")
            data = json.loads(r.findall(res.text)[0])
            first_section = data[next(iter(data))]
            movies_section = first_section['props']['data']['list']
            for movie in movies_section:
                titles.append(movie['title'])
                links.append(base + movie['slug'])

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(titles, links)), columns = ['Title', 'Link'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your expected output. Do you mean something like this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = "https://www.nowtv.com/stream/all-movies"
r = requests.get(link)
page = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

for dd in page.find_all("div", {"class":"ib-card-info-container"}):
    title = dd.find(class_="ib-card-title ib-colour-v1_white").text.strip()
    date = dd.find(class_="ib-card-availability-container ib-colour-20Grey").text.strip()
    print(title + " --> " + date)
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a great help for me. Does this do all 1400 movies? When I run it I get about 50 (I think)

Comment: I think this is because the page dynamically loads?
It seems the pages increment:
https://www.nowtv.com/stream/all-movies/page/24

Comment: Yes, because the page is rendered with javascript. One solution is the code by QHarr, or other you can use `selenium`